# Congratulations, Anime & Manga is graduating!

Tags: discussion

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Anime & Manga has already met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), and today joins in the new design-independent graduation process! Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

You've already had an election to have celebrated this previously, but now you will receive the remaining benefits detailed in this process, which include:

- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Answer (score 25):

**Graduation! Fantastic!**

It's not complete yet, but we've finally got the beta label removed, and that was my criteria for my celebration gif. So here it is:

[image: HappyGraduation]

I'm sorry if I missed anyone's name off, I just got a selection of users that I've had some kind of interaction with, and I couldn't put everyone down.

**Nonetheless, we all make up one great community, so this celebration is still for each and every user!**

## Happy graduation everyone!

Comment: It doesn't have my name :p....anyways nice image

Comment: It's not like it is a big @Matt-er that I am not included, B-b- Baka!

Comment: @Dimitrimx You're on there, second to last on the right hand side :L

Comment: I missed it due to the mis spelling ._. but senpai is happy then ;3

Comment: That gif made my day!

Comment: @Aʟᴀɢᴀʀᴏs Glad to hear it ^_^

Comment: @MattshinouMyouko We're not friends anymore.

Comment: @iKlsR Sorry </3